# Increasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)= \sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and $g(x)=\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ for $x\in \Bbb R$. Which of the following statement are necessarily correct?

$1)$ $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.
$2)$ $g$ is increasing function on $[0,\infty).$
$3)$ $g$ is decreasing function on $[0,\infty).$
$4)$ $f$ is decreasing function on $[0,\infty).$
I know from given two functions,I can say that $g=f'$.But I don't understand how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$$\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots $$

And

$$\cos x =1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\ldots $$

Comment: Do you understand how to proceed now ? @user159480

Answer (score 1):

Take $g'(x) = x - \sin x \implies g''(x) = 1 - \cos x \ge 0\implies g'(x) \ge g'(0) = 0 \implies g(x) \ge g(0) = 0\implies f'(x) = g(x) \ge 0 \implies f(x) \ge f(0) = 0$. This means $1), 2)$ are true.

Comment: From this can we say that $g''>0$ hence $g'$is increasing and hence g is increasing?If yes what about f?